# Issue related to Google App Engine query within a date range

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am concerned about querying entities this way

```
created_start = datetime.today()
created_start = created_start - timedelta(hours=1)
created_end = datetime.now()
a = Message.all()
a.filter('created >=',created_start)
a.filter('created <',created_end)
```

Due to the 1000 query results restriction. So two questions:

1. Will this work if `.all()` returns more that 1000 results? Or to put it in a different way. Will `all()` return more than a 1000 results incase there were more?
2. Is there a better way to achieve querying for entities between a given data range?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is good, since Version [1.3.6](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.3.6_-_August_17,_2010), query results are no longer capped at 1000.

You can iterate `a` entities until exhaustion or fetch chunks of entities using a [cursor](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_with_cursor).

Comment: Note that `.all()` does not return entities - it returns a Query object, on which `.fetch()` can be called to retrieve entities.